# What is the best way to print (save) a web form to the server in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, pdf, pdf-generation

To be more specific, I am building a Ruby on Rails application where a user will fill out a web form, but I need the [submit] action to PRINT/SAVE an uneditable (PDF or similar) document on the server.

For each user that fills out the form, it must generate a unique file with their registration info that can later be printed out.

Major karma points for anyone who can help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+create+pdf

Answer (score 0):

Check out Prawn: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

```
require 'prawn'

def create
  @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
  if @thing.save
    save_path = Rails.root.join('public','things',"#{@thing.id}.pdf")
    Prawn::Document.generate(save_path) do |pdf|
      pdf.text "Hello #{@thing.name}"
    end
    redirect_to @thing, :message => 'successfully created thing'
  end
end
```

Of course, you'd probably want to extract the document generation into its own class or template to keep view logic out of the controller, but hey, this is the simplest thing that will work.